# How does three.js render video according to spherical UV?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, webvr

I have a dash streaming video. According to its title, it is a 3*3. Now I can splice the complete video through the THREE,

```
   // 3*3 PlaneGeometry
   var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(400, 200, 3, 3);
    const video1 = document.getElementById("videos1");
       ...................
       ...................
    const texture1 = new THREE.VideoTexture(video3);
    texture1.maxFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
    texture1.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
       ...................
       ...................
    var geometryfaces = geometry.faces;
      for (let i = 0; i < geometryfaces.length; i++) {
        const faces = geometryfaces[i];
        materials[i] = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
          map: textures[i],
        });
      }
    var uv = [
        new THREE.Vector2(0, 0),
        new THREE.Vector2(0, 1),
        new THREE.Vector2(1, 1),
        new THREE.Vector2(1, 0),
      ];
     // Set the texture coordinates
      for (var m = 0; m < geometryfaces.length; m += 2) {
        geometry.faces[m].materialIndex = faceId;
        console.log(geometry.faces);
        geometry.faces[m + 1].materialIndex = faceId;
        geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][m] = [uv[2], uv[3], uv[1]];
        geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][m + 1] = [uv[3], uv[0], uv[1]];
        faceId++;
      }
      var bufferGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(geometry);
      var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);
      var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(bufferGeometry, material); //网格模型对象Mesh
```

This way I can get a full flat video, but this video is panoramic and I need to render it on the ball, and I don't know much about the UV of the ball。

I need help. Thank you

picture：[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxnJz.jpg)

picture2:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOPE2.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Three.js `SphereGeometry` automatically creates the UV mapping for you. Since the image you're using is equirectangular, you can just map the image onto the inside of the sphere for the effect you want:

```js
var camera, scene, renderer, vp, sphere;
vp = new THREE.Vector2(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

// Init WebGL stuff
function init() {
    // WebGL Renderer
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
    renderer.setSize(vp.x, vp.y);
    renderer.domElement.classList.add("canvasWebGL");

    // append to DOM
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    // scene
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xe1e1e1);

    // camera
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(55, vp.x / vp.y, 0.05, 100);

  // Sphere radius is large enough to surround the camera
  let sphereGeom = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 20, 128, 128 );
  
  // Just use your equirect image as the texture
    // And render the INSIDE of the sphere, not the outside
    const tex = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("https://i.imgur.com/1VECsLy.jpg");
  let sphereMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map: tex,
            side: THREE.BackSide
        });
  sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeom, sphereMat);
    scene.add(sphere);
}

function animate(s) {
    sphere.rotation.set(
        Math.cos(s / 3000), s / 3000, 0
    );

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

init();
animate(0);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.123/build/three.js"></script>
```

Read more about sphere geometry here: https://threejs.org/docs/?q=material#api/en/geometries/SphereGeometry

Comment: Sorry, MAYBE I didn't make it too clear, because a full panorama video consists of nine small videos (such as 3*3), AND I need to render the nine videos onto the sphere for rendering to get a full panorama,

Comment: The SphereGeometry constructor accepts several arguments for thetaStart, thetaLength, phiStart & phiLength. Just pass 1/3rd of a circle (2*pi / 3, in radians) for each section of video, then you can tile them 3 by 3.

Comment: Thank you. Well, I need to divide the ball into several pieces and then render it, but I don't know much about each tile,

Comment: Sorry, I haven't found the method yet. I'm not familiar with UV. Can I get your help?Thank you very much

Comment: @穿拖鞋的小涵 What have you tried? I've already shown you all the tools you need to create a 3x3 spherical tileable grid. `SphereGeometry(1, 32, 16, 0, Math.PI * 2 / 3, Math.PI / 3, Math.PI / 3)` All you need now is to build it yourself.